# Did Palpatine have a homeworld prior to the release Episode 1?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

We're all familiar with Palpatine's homeworld of Naboo in the current canon, as well as Legends material after the release of Episode 1.

What I want to look at is content from before that movie.  Did Palpatine have a homeworld, and what was it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I stopped reading Star Wars novels and comics during the prequels, I read all the novels before the prequels.  No.  There was nothing written before the prequels about the Emperor's background. The only thing we knew about him that was personal was his name, and only because it was in the Star Wars novelization.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence to back up this bold assertion?

Comment: Can I offer any evidence to back up the complete lack of any material dealing with the subject?   Not sure how I'd go about that.  But I was a reader of all the novels back then and remember the one where he came back as a series of clones.  He remained a man of mystery.

Comment: Well, a quote from Lucas explaining that this would finally be an opportunity to learn about Palatine's past would do it ;-)

Comment: It would help if you integrated your personal experience into your answer.